# Finding $a_n$ in a Laurent Series Expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$ for the function $\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ where |z-1| is between 0 and 1.  How would one find the 'formula' for $a_n$?  Is this similar to taylor series where the expansion should be produced and then the coefficients picked out?

Answer (score 2):

A trick of algebraic manipulations and use of known expansion series:
$$\frac{1}{z(z-1)} = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{(z-1)+1} 
= \frac{1}{z-1} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (z-1)^n $$
So explicitly, its Laurent series is
$$ \frac{1}{z(z-1)} = \frac{1}{z-1} - 1 + (z-1) - (z-1)^2 + (z-1)^3 + ... $$

Comment: So the key is simply to see a relevant algebraic manipulation to apply in hopes of obtaining an expansion?  Is your expansion above a Laurent series?  It appears to be a taylor series.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$ has a negative power term, $1/(z-1)$ that comes before the sum expression so it is a proper Laurent series. In any case you can always think of a Taylor series as a degenerate Laurent series with $0 = a_{-1} = a_{-2} = ...$.

Comment: Interesting, so Laurent series are really a generalization, not a separate object?

Comment: Yes. Every Taylor series is a Laurent series.